# Android: View.getBackground().getConstantState() not working for comparing background and drawable

Tags: java, android

I want to compare the background resource of the TextView to another drawable, but this does not work.

Most of answers of this question said that I should use `getConstantState()` but this doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?
Below is my code.

#### JAVA

```
TextView selected = findViewById(textViewIds.get((9*((9-i)))+(j-1)));

if (selected.getBackground().getConstantState()
    .equals(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Activity4.this, R.drawable.normal_light).getConstantState()))
    selected.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Activity4.this, R.drawable.blue));
else
    selected.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Activity4.this, R.drawable.normal_light));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConstantState()` does not work good in android and it isn't reliable.
Try using a different approach by exploiting the Tags of the element / background.
You could set the Tag of the background to any value you want and later comparing the Tags to another. You would use

```
if (selected.getBackground().getTag().toString().equals("background1")) {
...
}
```

Comment: Wow, this works! I set tag when TextView was add to ArrayList TextViewIds, and then retrieved that tag when selected was assigned. Thanks!!!

Comment: no Problem. Had the same issue just a while ago :)